# How to prevent hiding "seen" property on my Facebook messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I know my friends are using some apps to hide the "seen" property Facebook uses in chat and not showing it unless they want to. I' m not looking for those programs to use but to undo.

How to undo these programs and bring "seen" back, any idea?

I guess there is a web service that communicates with the server from the sender machine and returns the information about the receiver if he/she opened the message or not, but I'm not sure, and also I have no idea what are these programs doing.